# Power/Sample size calculation with R pwr.anova.test

Tags: r, anova, effect-size, statistical-power

I would like to use pwr.anova.test (R package) to calculate power or sample sizes etc.
The function needs several parameters:
pwr.anova.test(k = NULL, n = NULL, f = NULL, sig.level = 0.05, power = NULL)
I found one example (Peter Osmena, 2010) with input data:

μ1= 59; σ = 12; k = 3
μ2= 66; α = 0.05
μ3= 42; n = 4

From this, somehow "f" is calculated: f = 0.84

My question is how to calculate the effect size f.

Thank you for any help
Christian

Comment: Have you looked at Cohen's book?

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not have this book. I know that the calculation of f is explained there.

Comment: Just found the solution on [link](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html):